# passing GPS coordinates to activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to pass longitude and latitude variables into another activity for the Google maps fragment. So far I have managed to do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
i.putExtra(Double.toString(gettextLong), xLocation.getLongitude());
i.putExtra(Double.toString(gettextLat), xLocation.getLatitude());'
```

How do I receive it in the other activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Give relevant key like**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
i.putExtra("longitude", xLocation.getLongitude());
i.putExtra("latitude", xLocation.getLatitude());
```

**and in Main2 Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null && extras.getDouble("latitude") != null && extras.getDouble("longitude") != null) { 
double lat = extras.getDouble("latitude");
double lng = extras.getDouble("longitude");
}
```

Comment: getting some erros here: type mismatch cannot convert from bundle to intent. The method getDouble(String) is undefined for the type Intent

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
i.putExtra("lon", xLocation.getLongitude());
i.putExtra("lat", xLocation.getLatitude());
```

Like this:

```
int lat = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lat");
int lon = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lon");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) and [getDoubleExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%29) in yours second activity. But pass it in different way. First argument in putExtra should be some String but you have to know him, it is needed to use later in second activity. Like:

```
public static final String FIRST = "firstArgument";

i.putExtra(FIRST, xLocation.getLongitude());
```

And in Main2:

```
double i = getIntent().getDoubleExtra(Main.FIRST, 0);
```