# Android, Async, CallBack and UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, callback

I have one tough problem with combining this things in a whole.
Example: I want to get user location and update UI with latitude and longitude values. Because I stick up to the MVC pattern, I've created a separate class for this task (e.g. LocationWorker) and implemented it, following this guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrie..

Problem: In this case onConnected callback is located in the LocationWorker class and there is no way to communicate with UI. I've tried to implement onConnected callBack in MainActivity class (also add implementations for GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks), but I get an error (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'methodName' on a null object reference). It seems that callback executed before Worker actually does all work (After connection it's get user location, but OnConnectedCallback is being triggered right after the connection and before it has any time to get any data).

Anyway, it's a huge problem for me, what should I use in order to have Async tasks and be able to update UI when async task is done (and don't break MVC)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a get() in AsyncTask which will trigger when the request completes and will return the RETURN TYPE which you specified when you created your AsyncTask.

```
eg : ImageGrabber extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>
```

here the return type is Bitmap

So here's a sample for you, the below string will contain the response.

```
String jsonResponse = new JSONHelper().execute("http://example.com").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Async Class :

```
 //We can attach any object to the async class for result
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,MyObject,MyObject >{


    @Override
    protected MyObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Do the work to get your data
        //this is done in a background thread

        //prepare the result

        //MyObject object = new MyObject();
        //object.setLong(LONG);
        //object.setLang(LANG);


        //You can pass the result here 
        //return object;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyObject object) {
        super.onPostExecute(object);

        //Update UI
        //this is done on the main thread

        //access data from the Object result
        //object.getLong();
        //object.getLang();
    }
}
```

you initiate the async class :

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Good idea, although if I use described approach to get one's location, I already have a OnConnected callback method.
So, If I understand correctly, all I need is to call Async task from OnConnected callback? (In this case Async task prepares all data and gets it back to UI thread). If yes, just simply implement a OnConnected callback in MainActivity?

Comment: callback are a good approach yes i agree. Although as you know there are many options :)

Comment: wait if the data is coming with the callback there is no need to prepare it in the async..use async only for something that may block the UI

Comment: This exactly is the problem, callback is triggered when the connection is established to location services, but there is no data at this point. I think that I should start to receive data at this point, but how do I notify the UI that I have finished with fetching data? Can this be considered as a common and correct practice to do a callback?

Comment: no..yours is exactly a case to use async task...establishing connections must be done on a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify communication between the UI and any tasks I suggest using this framework to decouple your tasks from the UI: [Greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

An eventbus is all you need to accomplish what you are trying to do with a minimal learning curve.
Your UI will subscribe to events published by your task:

```
public class LocationEvent {
  private float lat, lng;
  public LocationEvent(float lat, float lng) { this.lat=lat; this.lng=lng; }
}

MainActivity {
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
  }

  public void onEvent(LocationEvent event) {
    // update user location
  }
}

LocationWorker {
  void doSomething() {
    eventBus.post(new LocationEvent(lat, lng));
  }
}
```

Instead of AsyncTask using a job-queue will make your tasks/jobs easier to manager with the added benefit of retries and persistence.

Take a look at [Path's Android Priority Job Queue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue)

Answer (score 0):

The EventBus looks promising.

Another alternative would be to use an Intent and Broadcast Receiver.

Example:

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter iFilter= new IntentFilter("updatelocation");
    iFilter.addAction("someOtherAction"); //if you want to add other actions to filter
    this.registerReceiver(br, iFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(br);
    super.onPause();
}

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("UpdateLocation")){

          //set these to member variables for later retrieval
          double lat = intent.getExtras().getDouble("lat");
          double lon = intent.getExtras().getDouble("lon");

          this.runOnUiThread(mUpdateLocation);
        }
    }

};

private final Runnable mUpdateLocation = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //TODO: Update your UI here                        
    }
};
```

Then, in your LocationWorker class, send an intent when the location has changed.  Make sure you have a reference to the application context in you LocationWorker class.

See this post: [passing GPS coordinates to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787086/passing-gps-coordinates-to-activity/17787242#17787242)

```
    //Make sure you have a reference to the application context
  Intent updateLocation= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  updateLocation.setAction("UpdateLocation");
  updateLocation.putExtra("lon", xLocation.getLongitude());
  updateLocation.putExtra("lat", xLocation.getLatitude());
  context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `new Asynctaskname.execute().get();` it will make the async task complete first and then executes the next.